# Issues importing the package statsmodels.api as sm

Tags: python, macos, import, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

Having issues importing the statsmodels.api package into my Jupyter notebook (On mac)

Already tried restarting the kernell and installing/uninstallin,

See below error message;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py in <module>
    125     try:
--> 126         from scipy.__config__ import show as show_config
    127     except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.__config__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
```

```
ImportError: Error importing SciPy: you cannot import SciPy while
        being in scipy source directory; please exit the SciPy source
        tree first and relaunch your Python interpreter.
```

Already tried restarting the kernell and installing/uninstallin,

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the ImportError message?